# bash_profile not working as it should

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables

Hi Im running linux angstrom distribution on a remote device, I added .bash_profile and .bashrc to /home/root since they didn't exist and I wrote this in them

```
PATH=/opt/qt-arm/lib:$PATH 
export PATH
```

But now when I login to this device and type $PATH I don't see the newly added path...Any Ideas??

Comment: I Found it, somehow I needed to create .profile in /home/root and fill it with the above 2 lines. Somehow Angstrom needs .profile and not .bash_profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I added .bash_profile and .bashrc to /home/root since ...

Look in `/etc/passwd` to check whether `/home/root` is actully root's home directory. On most linux distributions, it is just `/root`, not `/home/root`.

Update in response to comments:

`.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` are only inspected if the user's shell is `bash`. You can see what root's shell is in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: I Found it, somehow I needed to create .profile in /home/root and fill it with the above 2 lines. Somehow Angstrom needs .profile and not .bash_profile

Comment: @Kam that'd be because `root`'s shell is not bash. `/etc/passwd` will also well you what the shell is, and the man page for that shell should tell you what files it inspects.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the home directory of the root account is `/root` (not in `/home/root/`).

Comment: Your are correct in general, but Ångström uses /home/root (there is no /root).